# Rails 4: How do I prevent logged in user to impute email at checkout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was following a tutorial for practice and found an odd issue. Currently the way that its setup, any guest can create a shopping cart. Once at the checkout, the user has to input personal info including email which will register him as well as get mailing info.

Once the user does this, he/she gets an email stating the order and to set password for their new account using the email they just setup at the checkout. Problem is, if that same user who is logged in goes to checkout another item... they have input the same information including a new email which will create a new account, and the cycle continues.

The account email they just setup at the last checkout, is taken and they have to input a new email. You can see how odd this is, theres a continuous setting up of new account whenever someone wants to checkout an account.

I would like to prevent this so that once a user setups an account, they dont have to constantly setup a new account just to go through the checkout. What can be done about this problem? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
<h1>Checkout</h1>
<h2>You are checking out the following products:</h2>
<ul>
  <% @cart.items.each do |item| %>
    <li>
      <em>
        <%= item.quantity %>
      </em>
      <%= item.product.name %>
      <%= number_to_currency item.total_price %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<p>
  <strong>
    Total price:
    <%= number_to_currency @cart.total_price %>
  </strong>
</p>
<%= form_for @order_form, url: orders_path do |f| %>
  <%= render "orders/errors" %>
  <h3>Some of your personal details</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :user, f.object.user do |u| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>
        <%= u.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name", class: "form-control input-lg" %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
        <span class="help-block">This will help you track your order more effectively.</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="col-md-6">
          <%= u.text_field :address, placeholder: "Address", class: "form-control" %>
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-3">
          <%= u.text_field :postal_code, placeholder: "Postal code / Zipcode", class: "form-control" %>
        </p>
        <p class="col-md-3">
          <%= u.text_field :city, placeholder: "City", class: "form-control" %>
        </p>
      </div>
      <p>
        <%= u.country_select :country, { priority_countries: [ "GB", "US", "DE", "ES", "PT" ] }, { class: "form-control" } %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= u.text_field :phone, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone" %>
      </p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div id="dropin"></div>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Place order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<script>

  braintree.setup("#{@client_token}", 'dropin', {
    container: 'dropin'
  });

</script>
```

---

```
class OrderTransaction

  def initialize order, nonce
    @order = order
    @nonce = nonce
  end

  def execute
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: order.total_price,
      payment_method_nonce: nonce
    )
  end

  def ok?
    @result.success?
  end

  private

  attr_reader :order, :nonce
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :city, :country, :postal_code

  def full_address
  <<EOF
#{address}
#{postal_code} #{city}
#{country}
EOF
  end
end
```

---

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  def index
    @orders = Order.order(created_at: :desc).all
  end

  def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(
      user: User.new(order_params[:user]),
      cart: @cart
    )

    if @order_form.save
      notify_user
      if charge_user
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for placing the order."
      else
        flash[:warning] = <<EOF
Your order ID is #{@order_form.order.id}.
<br/>
Something went wrong.
EOF
        redirect_to new_payment_order_path(@order_form.order)
      end
    else
      render "carts/checkout"
    end
  end

  def update
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    @previous_state = @order.state

    if @order.update state_order_params
      notify_user_about_state
      redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Order was updated."
    end
  end

  def new_payment
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end

  def pay
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    transaction = OrderTransaction.new @order, params[:payment_method_nonce]
    transaction.execute
    if transaction.ok?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you for placing the order."
    else
      render "orders/new_payment"
    end
  end

  private

  def notify_user
    @order_form.user.send_reset_password_instructions
    OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order_form.order).deliver
  end

  def notify_user_about_state
    OrderMailer.state_changed(@order, @previous_state).deliver
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order_form).permit(
      user: [ :name, :phone, :address, :city, :country, :postal_code, :email ]
    )
  end


def charge_user(order) 
transaction = OrderTransaction.new order, params[:payment_method_nonce] 
transaction.execute 
transaction.ok? 
end

  def state_order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:state)
  end
end
```

---

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "sxxxxxx@gmail.com"

  def order_confirmation order
    @order = order
    mail to: order.user.email, subject: "Your order (##{order.id})"
  end

  def state_changed order, previous_state
    @order = order
    @previous_state = previous_state

    mail to: order.user.email, subject: "Your order (##{order.id}) has changed!"
  end

end
```

---

Comment: ask if the user is logged in inside the template and then don't render the email field. inside the controller then check if he's logged in and if so, just create another order instead of creating a new account and append the order

Comment: are you using sessions?

Comment: @HolyMoly, yes for carts

Comment: so the problem is probably that since the user is actually being created and saved upon placing an order, you need to log that user in automatically, right now it seems that they are saved but not logged in.

Comment: this is why they are being treated like a new user everytime

Comment: @HolyMoly, I used to have users sign in and then reference users information when they order. I'm not sure how to do it with this, `@order_form = current_user.order.build`?

Comment: well i can understand not wanting to require a user to sign up before shopping. but since they will have to submit all that info and be saved before purchasing, what I would do is add a helper method to my sessions that logs in the user, then in my user controller call that helper when the user submits their info and is saved. That way once they are saved, they are logged in right away.

Comment: and with the code in your comment above, if the current_user is not logged in then current_user is nil so it would throw an error

Comment: I'm still unsure, I was able to hide the email information being needed but what about validation, the email is required. Would be nice if it was already in the database and didn't need to validated. But I'm still stuck as to how to implement it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90667/discussion-between-jamesrocky-and-holymoly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the input from the view, with an if statement similar to this one in the 
controller.

have a look at devises, user_signed_in? or current_user methods.

Also in the first controller you would proceed like this

```
def create

    order_user == user_signed_in? ? current_user : User.new(order_params[:user])

    @order_form = (
      user: order_user,
      cart: @cart
    )
[...]
```